# Rendering a cube defined by planes (Valve map file format)

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, rendering, monogame

Currently i am trying to render a cube within a monogame application.
I am using the Valve map file format. The map format is described in the following wiki page:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/MAP_file_format.

Importing the format is straight forward and no problem at all.
The important section is the description of the planes. The format looks like this:

```
{
    ( x1 y1 z1) ( x2 y2 z2) ( x3 y3 z3) texture_name  ...
    ( x1 y1 z1) ( x2 y2 z2) ( x3 y3 z3) texture_name  ...
    ( x1 y1 z1) ( x2 y2 z2) ( x3 y3 z3) texture_name  ...
    ( x1 y1 z1) ( x2 y2 z2) ( x3 y3 z3) texture_name  ...
    ( x1 y1 z1) ( x2 y2 z2) ( x3 y3 z3) texture_name  ...
    ( x1 y1 z1) ( x2 y2 z2) ( x3 y3 z3) texture_name  ...
}
```

Every line defines one plane. To define one actual plane, three points must be given (shown by x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 and x3, y3, z3).

```
plane ((vertex) (vertex) (vertex))
```

This defines the three points that will be used to set the plane's orientation and position in the three-dimensional world. The first marks the bottom left of the face, the second marks the top left, and the third marks the top right. Below is an animation of a simple brush being build from six planes via CSG. The first, second and third plane point is represented by red, green and blue dots.

[image: Animation]

So i am loading these planes and render them as triangles.
The redering result within my monogame application is this:

[image: Rendering Result]

So obviously there are missing some parts in the cube.

I am creating the map file with worldcraft hammer editor. So the result should look like this:

[image: Worldcraft Hammer]

**Vertex-Creation-Method:**

Transformation of brushes and faces to xna VertexPositionColor types.

```
    private VertexPositionColor[] CreateVertexPositions(Brush brush)
    {
        VertexPositionColor[] vertices = new VertexPositionColor[brush.Faces.Count * 3];

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < brush.Faces.Count; i++)
        {
            Face brushFace = brush.Faces[i];
            Color color = ColorUtils.GenerateRandomColor(Color.Wheat);

            vertices[i + j + 0] = new VertexPositionColor( // bottom left of the face
                new Vector3(brushFace.V1.X, brushFace.V1.Y, brushFace.V1.Z), color
            );
            vertices[i + j + 1] = new VertexPositionColor( // top left of the face
                new Vector3(brushFace.V2.X, brushFace.V2.Y, brushFace.V2.Z), color
            );
            vertices[i + j + 2] = new VertexPositionColor( // top right of the face
                new Vector3(brushFace.V3.X, brushFace.V3.Y, brushFace.V3.Z), color
            );

            j = j + 2;
        }

        return vertices;
    }
```

**BrushFace Model**:

```
public sealed class Face
{
    public Vertex3 V1 { get; set; }
    public Vertex3 V2 { get; set; }
    public Vertex3 V3 { get; set; }
    public string TextureName { get; set; }
    public Plane P1 { get; set; }
    public Plane P2 { get; set; }
    public int Rotation { get; set; }
    public float XScale { get; set; }
    public float YScale { get; set; }
}
```

**Rendering-Method**:

```
    public override void Render(ICamera camera)
    {
        _effect.Projection = camera.Projection;
        _effect.View = camera.View;
        _effect.World = camera.World;

        RasterizerState rasterizerState = new RasterizerState();
        rasterizerState.CullMode = CullMode.None;
        rasterizerState.FillMode = FillMode.Solid;
        GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState;

        foreach (EffectPass pass in _effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();
            GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, _vertices.ToArray(), 0, (_vertices.Count / 3), VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
        }
    }
```

I am missing a fundemental piece. How can i create a cube out of the given planes?

I am not asking for a complete code nor a finished solution but for someone pushing me into the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

**Update**

I made a very simple project for this and uploaded it to my OneDrive account:

[OneDrive Link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgTD16u3PEi6hQJzzgegLYyEynzQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cube is made up of 6 quads ( 6 rectangles). A quad is two triangles, not one. And since a quad is 2 triangles, it has 6 vertices. So to render a cube, you must handle 36 vertices.

All the info to make up the 36 vertices are in those 18 vertices that make up your planes.

For all 36 vertices, there are only 6 unique component values. For any one of the 36 vertices that make up a cube, there can only be 2 possible X values, 2 possible Y values, and 2 possible Z values. All 36 vertices are made up of the various combinations of those 6 unique values.

Your task is to iterate through the 6 planes (18 vertices) and pull the 6 unique component values out, and then make up your 36 vertices out of those 6 component values. Then populate your VertexBuffer with the 36 vertices.